# ORA-12560: TNS:protocol adapter error logging into Oracle as Sysdba

Tags: oracle, oracle-19c

I have Oracle 19c installed on my windows 10 machine.

When I try to log in as `sysdba` I am getting an `ORA-12560: TNS:protocol adapter error` error:

```
sqlplus / as sysdba

SQL*Plus: Release 19.0.0.0.0 - Production on Sat Sep 25 16:47:45 2021
Version 19.3.0.0.0

Copyright (c) 1982, 2019, Oracle.  All rights reserved.

ERROR:
ORA-12560: TNS:protocol adapter error


Enter user-name:
```

My database is called `aws` and I've verified that my listener (called LISTENER1) is running:

```
lsnrctl status LISTENER1

LSNRCTL for 64-bit Windows: Version 19.0.0.0.0 - Production on 25-SEP-2021 16:50:25

Copyright (c) 1991, 2019, Oracle.  All rights reserved.

Connecting to (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=DESKTOP-0T5DL1G)(PORT=1555)))
STATUS of the LISTENER
------------------------
Alias                     LISTENER1
Version                   TNSLSNR for 64-bit Windows: Version 19.0.0.0.0 - Production
Start Date                25-SEP-2021 16:29:29
Uptime                    0 days 0 hr. 20 min. 55 sec
Trace Level               off
Security                  ON: Local OS Authentication
SNMP                      OFF
Listener Parameter File   D:\Oracle_Home\instantclient\network\admin\listener.ora
Listener Log File         D:\Oracle_Home\app09\oracle\base\diag\tnslsnr\DESKTOP-0T5DL1G\listener1\alert\log.xml
Listening Endpoints Summary...
  (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=tcp)(HOST=DESKTOP-0T5DL1G)(PORT=1555)))
  (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=ipc)(PIPENAME=\\.\pipe\EXTPROC1555ipc)))
  (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=tcps)(HOST=DESKTOP-0T5DL1G)(PORT=5500))(Security=(my_wallet_directory=D:\ORACLE_HOME\APP09\ORACLE\BASE\admin\aws\xdb_wallet))(Presentation=HTTP)(Session=RAW))
Services Summary...
Service "38b9417aa9264443afd1d72225643c01.jokefire.com" has 1 instance(s).
  Instance "aws", status READY, has 2 handler(s) for this service...
Service "52448234712340b69f274bcc790ecfe0.jokefire.com" has 1 instance(s).
  Instance "aws", status READY, has 2 handler(s) for this service...
Service "CLRExtProc" has 1 instance(s).
  Instance "CLRExtProc", status UNKNOWN, has 1 handler(s) for this service...
Service "aws.jokefire.com" has 1 instance(s).
  Instance "aws", status READY, has 2 handler(s) for this service...
Service "pdb1.jokefire.com" has 1 instance(s).
  Instance "aws", status READY, has 2 handler(s) for this service...
The command completed successfully
```

I've set my `oracle_sid` to the same name as my hostname:

`set oracle_sid=DESKTOP-0T5DL1G`

I'm not seeing any errors in the alert logs, but I do see this warning from around the time I tried logging in:

```
<msg time='2021-09-25T16:41:13.815-04:00' org_id='oracle' comp_id='tnslsnr'
 type='UNKNOWN' level='16' host_id='DESKTOP-0T5DL1G'
 host_addr='fe80::4872:2113:3a49:48e3%7' pid='25252'>
 <txt>WARNING: Subscription for node down event still pending
 </txt>
</msg>
```

I am new to Oracle. Why am I getting this error and how do I solve this?

Comment: Just as an aside, you are attempting what is known as a BEQueath connection - that is an inter-process call, as opposed to a network connection.  That said, the listener is not at all involved.

Comment: cool, thank you for pointing that out!

Comment: Start by checking the oracle logs. Find the Oracle install folder and then in there, find th \diag\rdbms\aws\aws\trace\alert_aws.log file. See if you can find any error messages in there that point to a crash condition.

If that fails to lead to anything... It isn't common, but I've seen Oracle flake out and get lost, especially if the system doesn't have enough RAM or other processes are taking too much memory from what Oracle wants... there may be a less brute-force fix, but in my case, stopping/restarting Oracle instance and listener services was about it.

Answer (score 1):

The `oracle_sid` parameter should be the SID of your instance. According to your listener status output your SID is `AWS`.
So try:

```
set oracle_sid=AWS
sqlplus / as sysdba
```

Remember, if you've set this up as a multitenant DB (which is the recommended option and the only one supported in newer versions) this will connect you to the `CDB$ROOT` container, you can use

```
alter session set container=<pdb name>;
```

ie

```
alter session set container=pdb1;
```

to switch to your PDB.

Comment: Hi! Thanks for answering. I tried setting the sid to `aws` but I am still not able to log into the database. Here is what I get:

`PS D:\Oracle_Home> set oracle_sid=AWS
PS D:\Oracle_Home> sqlplus / as sysdba

SQL*Plus: Release 19.0.0.0.0 - Production on Sat Sep 25 21:56:28 2021
Version 19.3.0.0.0

Copyright (c) 1982, 2019, Oracle.  All rights reserved.

ERROR:
ORA-12560: TNS:protocol adapter error


Enter user-name:`

Comment: Note that `ORACLE_SID` is _case sensitive_; both the name and the value. `oracle_sid` is not valid; it should be capitalized, and the SID appears to be `aws`, not `AWS`.

Comment: Fire up powershell, what’s the output of `(get-service oracleservice*).name`? Try lowercase aws. You don’t need to worry about the case of `oracle_sid` in Windows

Comment: In Windows, oracle_sid and the SID are not case sensitive. I can confirm that on Oracle versions 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 18, and 19 (gawd I'm getting old).  That may be not be true in linux?

Comment: @CaM agreed, not sure why I entertained the idea :) in Linux pretty much everything is case sensitive, Windows is much friendlier ;) I’ve spotted the issue in the questioners comment though - `set oracle_sid` Was run from powershell not cmd, so the syntax should be `$env:oracle_sid='Aws'`